# Leer array retornado de una clase

Tags: php, poo

Buen dia

Tengo la siguiente clase la cual me crea un pedido de un cliente

```
require("conexion.php");

    class Pedido extends Conexion{
        
        public function __construct(){
            $this->conexion = new Conexion();
            $this->conexion = $this->conexion->conectarse();
        } 
        
        public function crearPedido(string $nombre_cliente, string $orden_compra, string $fecha_pedido, string $fecha_cargue)          
        {
           
            $sql = "INSERT INTO pedidos (nombre_cliente, orden_compra, fecha_pedido, fecha_cargue) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
            $insert = $this->conexion->prepare($sql);
            $arrData = array($nombre,$orden_compra,$fecha_pedido,$fecha_cargue);
            $ejecutar=$insert->execute($arrData);
            $idInsertado=$this->conexion->lastInsertId();          
            
            $array_respuesta = array("pedido guardado",$idInsertado);
            //este print_r de prueba funciona bien, me muestra efectivamente el ultimo registro insertado
            //ejemplo Array ( [0] => pedido guardado [1] => 23 )      
            return ($array_respuesta);                   
                
        }
        
    }
```

El problema esta en el otro archivo php donde instancio el objeto

```
<?php
    require("pedido.php");
    //recibo array del ajax
    $array_objetos_presentaciones = json_decode($_POST['array']);
    //aqui probé lo que recibí y efectivamente si esta bien
    //print_r($array_objetos_presentaciones);

    $nombre_cliente = $array_objetos_presentaciones[0]->nombre_cliente;
    $orden_compra = $array_objetos_presentaciones[0]->orden_compra;
    $fecha_pedido = $array_objetos_presentaciones[0]->fecha_pedido;
    $fecha_cargue = $array_objetos_presentaciones[0]->fecha_cargue;
    

    $objPedido = new Pedido;
    $objPedido->crearPedido($nombre_cliente,$orden_compra,$fecha_pedido,$fecha_cargue);
    
//aqui he intentado con print_r y echo, no obtengo el array que si obtengo en la funcion de la clase
    echo($objPedido);
?>
```

lo que quiero es validar en la posicion 0 si el pedido se guardó y en la posicion 1 con que ID en la base de datos se guardó ya que mas adelante quiero responder otra cosas como por ejemplo, Array ( [0] => pedido ya existe [1] => "no aplica" )

Comment: Tienes que asignar la respuesta a la llamada crearPedido a una variable y lugo imprimir dicha variable. Ahora nos estas asignando la respuesta por lo que no la capturas y no puedes mostrarla.

Comment: Gracias!! olvidé eso!